# C++ initialization list and constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14

C++14 provides the initialization list and we can use it to initialize elements in a class or struct. What are the differences of the two initialization manners in the following code?

```
struct MyItem {
  MyItem() : val{0} {}
  int val;
};

struct MyItem {
  MyItem() {}
  int val{0};
};
```

Answer (score 4):

In your case, there is no difference. The first case uses a *mem-initializer* to initialize `val`. The second uses a *brace-or-equal-initializer*. A *brace-or-equal-initializer* will be used for a member when there is no *mem-initializer* present for that member. If there is a *mem-initializer*, it takes precedence, and the *brace-or-equal-initializer* is ignored.

One can certainly construct contrived examples where there is a difference...

```
const int i = 42;

struct S1 {
    S1(int i): val{i} {} // sets val to the parameter i
    int val;
};

struct S2 {
    S2(int i) {} // param is ignored
    int val{i}; // sets val to 42
};
```